# Android speed optimization: Load fragments in background

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I am developing an Android app and I'm using fragments. I create them all while the app is starting and then just switch the single fragments. It works fine, but is there a possibility to create them all in the background when the app is already started?

Comment: If it's working fine, then what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It is very slow. It loads already 10 seconds on one fragment. And I'd like to have about 5 fragments of this size. It is possible that my layouts are too big, but I don't know what I could change..

Comment: Fragment instantiation in itself is a relatively cheap operation, certainly nowhere near 10 seconds. If you're loading some data in it, then _that_ might take some time depending on the type of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "background".

A `Fragment` has to be created on the main/UI thread, so no there is no way to instantiate them on an alternate thread.

However, you can delay the creation of the `Fragment` collection as such:

```
    View view = findViewById(R.id.yourView);
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // create fragments here
        }
    }, 2000);
```

This will cause the `run()` method to be executed 2 seconds later. Anything inside that method will execute on the main thread.